# Swift builder pattern where order matters

Tags: swift, design-patterns, builder, fluent

So I would like to create a builder where the order matters. However, I don't want to concern the caller with what that order is.

```
class myClass {
    private var a: Bool
    private var b: Bool
    private var c: Bool
    init() {
        a = false
        b = false
        c = false
    }
    func build() { // enforces order
        if a {
            // build a
        }
        if b {
            // build b
        }
        if c {
            // build c
        }
        return
    }
    func setA() -> myClass {
        a = true
        return self
    }
    func setB() -> myClass {
        b = true
        return self
    }
    func setC() -> myClass {
        c = true
        return self
    }
}
```

This is my current solution. This way the caller does not need to care about the order. The build function will handle the order. And this is what I want. My question however is, can I do this without using bools? is there a more clean solution to achieve the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "more clean"? Your solution look pretty good. And what do you mean "without using bools"? You need something boolean-ish to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use an array instead to keep track of what should be done. From your code I assume the work done for each part can be seen as a function taking no arguments and returning Void so I create an array of that function type and each setX function will add the corresponding function to the array at the right index and then the functions are called in the order they appear in the array.

```
class MyClass {
    typealias BuildFunc = ()->Void

    private var workflow = Array<BuildFunc?>(repeating: nil, count: 3)

    func build() { 
        workflow.compactMap { $0 }.forEach { f in
            f()
        }
    }

    func setA() -> MyClass {
        workflow[0] = a
        return self
    }
    func setB() -> MyClass {
        workflow[1] = b
        return self
    }
    func setC() -> MyClass {
        workflow[2] = c
        return self
    }

    func a() -> Void {
        print("a")
    }
    func b() -> Void {
        print("b")
    }
    func c() -> Void {
        print("c")
    }
}
```

Example

```
let build = MyClass()

build.setC().setA()
build.build()
```